# Java jersey client consumes JsonArray of jsonArray

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey

I have a special kind of parsing JSON url :

```
[{"exchangeRates":[{"currencyISO":"AUD","currencyShortName":"dolar"}]}]
```

to do that i need to pass by a proxy and a jersey client :

```
URLConnectionClientHandler ch  = new URLConnectionClientHandler(new ConnectionFactory());
            Client client = new Client(ch);         
            WebResource resource = client.resource("https://api.xxxx");
            resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            ExchangeRates[] responseMsg = resource.path("/openapi/xxxx").get(ExchangeRates[].class);
```

the response is :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.xxx.ExchangeRates out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@236cfcf; line: 1, column: 1]
```

ExchangeRates is a list of ExchangeRate object.
I can't find a way how to parse this json.Any recommandation ?

Comment: Try replacing `ExchangeRates[] responseMsg` with `ExchangeRates responseMsg` and `get(ExchangeRates[].class)` with `get(ExchangeRates.class)`

Comment: same thing but with different error : an not deserialize instance of com.socgen.xxx.ExchangeRates out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: I'm not quite sure if a JSON String that you have described is considered as standard JSON, since JSON strings will be wrapped inside `{` and `}`.

Comment: yes, but my main problem is how to do that with java, read json url file, then parse it to java class?

Comment: Well, in that case you need to read the JSON as String, append parenthesis, and then use an `ObjectMapper` to parse to a Java class instance.

Comment: Thanks, it works, otherwise i've removed the '[]'